# Trying to debug safari on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, safari-web-inspector

I've set up windows to debug safari.

I've managed to get everything except

```
npm install remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter -g
```

to install correctly

```
npm WARN ws@7.2.5 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.2.5 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

And when I listen on port 9000 nothing happens:

```
remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter -- port=9000
```

I've tried to install the missing peer stuff

```
npm install --save-dev "utf-8-validate@^5.0.2"  
npm install --save-dev "bufferutil@^4.0.1"
```

which seems to work but I get

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\package.json'
npm WARN system32 No description
npm WARN system32 No repository field.
npm WARN system32 No README data
npm WARN system32 No license field.
```

for both of them - node is installed.

Can someone help or point me at the right way to load the peers - I can't find any other bits of code to try!

thanks

Comment: Reads like it has the wrong path for `package.json`. I wouldn't expect it to be in `C:\Windows\System32`. Do you need to set a path for the webkit adapter?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: It will be where the node_modules are. It looks like you've done a global install `-g`, so I believe you can run `npm root -g` to find out exactly where that is.

Comment: so I've fount the node modules C:\Users\Ops\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules  how do I set up the path that you think I need?  The package.json file is in

Comment: I would first see if you have anything for the webkit adapter in there and see if you can run it when you change your directory to that folder.

Comment: C:\Users\Ops\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter  has the package.json file in it.  how do I include it so that it can be run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213501/discussion-between-user1616338-and-ash).

Comment: Run `cd C:\Users\Ops\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter` and then try running `remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter -- port=9000` again, or `npm remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter -- port=9000`.

Comment: This didn't work remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter : The term 'remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.